# Fragmentar string con un delimitador en Bash Script

Tags: bash, script, cut

Tengo la siguiente string con el siguiente formato:

```
var1=Dato1;Dato2;Dato3;Dato4;Dato5;Dato6;Dato7;Dato8;Dato9;Dato10,Dato12,Dato13
```

Necesito poder fragmentar esa string en un patrón determinado, ya que de esa string solo me importa el patron que va del Dato1 al Dato6, del Dato7 al Dato12, del Dato13 al Dato18. Saltos de 6 en 6.

Existe alguna forma de llegar a esa lógica? Probé de multiples formas, se que si hago un: "cut -s -d ';' -f1-6" estaria extrayendo la información que necesito, pero hay una forma de replicar ese mismo patron indefinidamente sobre una string?

Lo que estoy intentando lograr es algo similar a un Explode en PHP, pero en Bash.

Originalmente el archivo presentaba el siguiente formato también:

- Dato1;
- Dato2;
- Dato3;
- Dato4;
- Dato5;
- etc;

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haces con `cut` ya está bien. Simplemente pásale la cadena en lugar del fichero:

```
cut ... <<< "cadena"
```

Con tus datos:

```
$ var1="Dato1;Dato2;Dato3;Dato4;Dato5;Dato6;Dato7;Dato8;Dato9;Dato10,Dato12,Dato13"
$ cut -s -d ';' -f1-6 <<< "$var1"
Dato1;Dato2;Dato3;Dato4;Dato5;Dato6
```